# Excel VBA Replace cell with answer from formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet with a bunch of headers, but some do not have dashes.
I need them all to have dashes, except total.

Ex:
[image: Column Headers]

I've written the formula that will add the dashes to the headers:

```
=IF(A1="","",IF(A1="TOTAL","TOTAL",REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""), 1, 0, "-")))
```

However, the problem is that I need this in a VBA macro, and it needs to replace the existing headers with keeping the same formatting.

I'm not sure how to write this, this is what I got so far:

```
Sub AddDash()
Dim MaxColumn As String
MaxColumn = Range("AY1").End(xlToLeft)
For i = 1 To TotalRows
Formula = "=IF(A1="","",IF(A1="TOTAL","TOTAL",REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""), 1, 0, "-")))"
Next i
End Sub
```

Is this possible to do?

I've seen something similar, but I do not understand it enough to make it work for my situation

```
With Sheet1
    With Range(.Cells(3,3), .Cells(.Rows.Count,3).End(xlup))
        With .Offset(0, Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count +3)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(RC3,""-"",""""), 9, 0, ""-""), 7, 0, ""-"")"
         End With
         .Value = .Offset(0, Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count +3).Value
         .Offset(0, Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count +3).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
End With
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Not sure I follow you. If you put a formula in the cell, it will overwrite the contents of the cell. If you put text in the cell, it will overwrite the formula. I'm not sure how your formula to edit text in place will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? I have commented the code but if you still have a question then feel free to ask.

```
Sub AddDash()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lCol As Long, i As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        '~~> Find the last column in row 1
        lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        '~~> Loop through the columns in row 1
        For i = 1 To lCol
            '~~> Check 1 : Cell is not empty
            '~~> Check 2 : Cell doesn't have TOTAL
            '~~> Check 3 : Cell Doesn't already have a Dash
            If Len(Trim(.Cells(1, i).Value)) <> 0 And _
               UCase(Trim(.Cells(1, i).Value)) <> "TOTAL" And _
               Left(Trim(.Cells(1, i).Value), 1) <> "-" Then
                '~~> Add Dash
                .Cells(1, i).Value = "-" & .Cells(1, i).Value
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Dude, wow! This is so well written. I was approaching it completely wrong, haha. I feel foolish. Your code is so clean, I have to learn how to write like you. It's beautiful. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)